# How to get full html code after rendering php

Tags: php

I am trying to make some cache system for my php engine, so I need to save html source of just rendered php file. 
I know that I could create some $htmlsource var and render all page to it, but there is a lot of work to change for that.
I would like to get just rendered html from some buffer or whatever, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
//here is php code prints some content
$content = ob_get_content();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're heading in the wrong direction. The best approach is to use a mixture of different caching technologies.

- There are [PHP accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators).
- There are easy-to-use key-value store daemons such as [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/) (cache the results of expensive database queries).
- There are options available for [client-side caching](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what output buffering does for you.

Before you start output any data issue a ob_start command. and before you are done do $html = ob_get_clean();

Here is a minimal example of the steps needed to implement a page caching system

```
$html = get_from_cache($cachekey);
if(!$html){
   ob_start();
   // output your page.
   $html = ob_get_clean();
   update_cache($cachekey, $html);
}
echo $html;
```